# Create a title page and a separate abstract page with elsarticle`s frontmatter environment

Tags: elsarticle, front-matter

I have to use the elsarticle document class and its frontmatter environment. However, I need the title page to be separated on two pages - title information on page 1 and abstract and keywords on page 2. How can I add a pagebreak before the abstract begins?

```
\documentclass[review, 12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of TBD}
%% APA style
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title here}

\author{author 1\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}\fnref{myfootnotetel}}
\ead{email@mail.com}

\address{address}

\fntext[myfootnotetel]{Tel}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
% PAGEBREAK needed HERE
\begin{abstract}
abstract text
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\texttt skeyword1\sep keywod2\\
%\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00  
\vfill{}
Funding note.
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but to me it doesn`t seem like an answer to my question - I need to modify it because the journal editor wants it that way.

Comment: It is a complete and utter mysery why Journal Editors require authors to Change the appearance of their work. Especially since templates are involved.

Comment: Totally agree, however, the template is a general elsevier template - each elsevier journal is free to require any changes they`d like to have, so I have to customize the template. No matter whether I like it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to actually change the elsarticle.sty by adding a clearpage in the following way:

```
\long\def\pprintMaketitle{\clearpage  %add a clearpage
  \iflongmktitle\if@twocolumn\let\columnwidth=\textwidth\fi\fi
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \printFirstPageNotes
  \begin{center}%
 \thispagestyle{pprintTitle}%
   \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
    \clearpage
    %\hrule\vskip12pt    %remove the horizontal lines
    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    %\hrule\vskip12pt    %remove the horizontal lines
    \end{center}%
  \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}%
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be the journal editor's job to change the formatting or to provide you with a modified version of `elsarticle`: the purpose of such a template is getting from authors a clean typescript that can be easily adapted to the needs of a specific journal.

Anyway, you can get what you want by patching a few commands.

```
\documentclass[review, 12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of TBD}
%% APA style
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
 {\hrule}
 {\clearpage\hrule}
 {}{}
\appto\endfrontmatter{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title here}

\author{author 1\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}\fnref{myfootnotetel}}
\ead{email@mail.com}

\address{address}

\fntext[myfootnotetel]{Tel}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
% PAGEBREAK needed HERE
\begin{abstract}
abstract text
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\texttt skeyword1\sep keywod2\\
%\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00  
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some information in the author's guide.
Use this code to create a page break after your author information:

```
\begin{document}
\newpageafter{author}
\begin{frontmatter}
```

You can also use `\newpageafter{title}` or `\newpageafter{abstract}` for other page breaks.

Comment: This is the best answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @egreg I have done the following two steps:

1. before `\journal{...}` I have added `\usepackage{etoolbox}`
2. after `\journal{...}` I have added

```latex
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
 {\hrule}
 {\clearpage\hrule}
 {}{}
\appto\endfrontmatter{\clearpage}
```